# JavaScript: unsure how call and apply relate to the arguments object in this function

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a abstract way, I totally understand what's going on. This is a great way to have unlimited number of arguments for the functions being passed into the `calculate` object.

```
var calculate = function(){

    var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
    return fn.apply(null, arguments);

},

sum = function(x,y){

    return x + y;

},

diff = function(x,y){

    return x - y;

};
```

This appears to be the crux of the function. We are using the `apply` method here to allow the `arguments` object to have the `pop` method of the `Array prototype`

Where I am unclear is...

*The TUT says this going to give us the `Function` object and assign it to the `fn` variable, it will also remove that `Function` object from the `arguments` object, because of the `pop` method. (The `pop` method removes the last item of an array, and assigns it to what ever called the pop method) In this case the `fn` variable. We end up with an `arguments` object, which no longer has a function object, it just has all the numeric values*

```
var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
        return fn.apply(null, arguments);
```

Recently, I started to realize perhaps my misunderstanding is I am seeing the `fn` variable as just that, and not the function which will be ultimately passed into the `calculate` object.

Thanks in advance for helping me understand this!!

Comment: I am not sure what your actual question is.

Comment: same here, to me it seems that you understand what's going on

Comment: What "TUT" are you talking about? From where do you quote this?

Comment: @Bergi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U5uZknN9BQ&list=PLOxOmO43E6Jt4GfZtF8yR6KghIdmc7715&index=6

Comment: I guess I am not understanding where the `Function` object is coming from? The one which will be assigned to the `fn` variable. `var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);`

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: Have you seen how `calculate` is called? That's where the arguments, including the function, are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax of apply:

```
function.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
```

Let's use calculate on sum:

```
calculate(10, 15, sum);
```

Inside calculate:

In the start - `arguments = [10, 15, sum];` Note that arguments are not an array, but an array like object - using the array notation is just easier

```
var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
```

Arguments is not an array, so it doesn't have the pop method, we take the pop method from the array prototype and run it on arguments - which means that we use arguments as the 'this' prop of `.pop()`. This returns last parameter of arguments, which is supposed to be the function (sum in this case).

After pop - `arguments = [10, 15];`

Now we take the arguments and use the 2nd part of the `.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])` method - argsArray.

In `fn.apply(null, arguments)` thisArg = null (doesn't matter as the function sum doesn't use this), and now apply assigns the arguments to the parameters in the 'array' order - x (1st) = 10, y (2nd) = 15, and runs the function.

Comment: Thanks so much! My only question is on the return line in the calculate function, why do you even need to use apply method again? Haven't you removed the sum argument with the pop method on the previous line? Don't you now have a mechanism to pass all the arguments you want?

Comment: You have an array of arguments, and you want to use it on a function that needs parameters that are not in an array structure fn(x, y). .apply is the mechanism that takes the arguments, and put each of them in the right place according to the items order.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! But you couldn't use `fn.call(null, arguments)` instead right?
We are using `apply` because of the second parameter it accepts is a array, and we need that in our case...

Comment: Exactly - if we used `fn.call(null, arguments)` on fn(x, y) it would result in x = arguments.

Comment: THANK YOU, for taking the time to walk me through it!

Comment: My pleasure - these are really useful methods (.call and .apply), but somehow hard to understand despite their simple use.